Control.set_focus_neighbor ## How to get the correct node path to the target node?
I've got a list of nodes. Each node in the list should have the next one as it's neighbor. Iterating is the easy part, I can handle it. I have problems with setting the neighbors in the code:
item.set_focus_neighbor(SIDE_BOTTOM, PATH)
Instead of PATH I tried:
get_node("/root").get_path_to(item_list[item_index + 1])
self.get_path_to(item_list[item_index + 1])
get_path_to(item_list[item_index + 1]) (I know it's the same as self)
With these I get an error: "Node not found: "../../ ..."" (or another path to the perfectly existing node) "(relative to /root/..." (another path to the same node).
What path is it asking for and how do I get the correct one? Why couldn't they have made it so I could just pass the node reference:(

I figured it out. The solution was to explicitly call NodePath as in:
NodePath(item.get_path())
get_path() returns an absolute path in String format
